# Adjust / filter object value in ng-repeat

Tags: regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to apply a regex to strip all non-digits from an object's value in an ng-repeat.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
   <span>{{obj.value.replace(/\D/g, '')}}</span>
```

Any idea on how to do this best?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it that way, but the best way would probably be to create a custom filter.

```
app.filter('onlyNumbers', function() {
  return function(val) {
    return val.replace(/\D/g, '');
  };
});
```

Then:

```
<span>{{ obj.value | onlyNumbers }}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! worked great. How can I apply that filter when saving that variable? ie `ng-click="number = obj.value;"` ideally it would be `ng-click="number = obj.value|onlyNumbers;"` so that number is ONLY the numeric values from `obj.value`

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but try ng-click="number = (obj.value | onlyNumbers);".